# How do I show only the column name of the SQL table

Tags: php, mysqli

Currently my code consists of

```
$sql = "SHOW columns FROM tblexercise";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($row as $field => $value) {

      echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

This allows me to show the column names but it also includes all the attributes and types etc.
is there any way to show just the column name?

Comment: Drop the `foreach` then and just select the columns you want in the query and echo those out. You're already inside a loop, so why use another? Either use a `foreach` or a `while`, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop inside a loop. You only need one `foreach` loop and then you can access the key `Field` which holds the name of the column. The query `SHOW COLUMNS` is explained in the [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-columns.html). You can check in that link what are the results of this query and their sample values. Then you can decide which values you want to access.

```
$result = $conn->query("SHOW columns FROM tblexercise");
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Field'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```